# incompatible type inference variable e#1 has incompatible bounds equality constraints: Area

Tags: java, compiler-errors, guava

So i have this list that will show list of area, but i wanted to filter the list when i invoke `filterList()` method. I can make a full list (without filter).

The commented code is how i did my "full list of area".

```
private List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<Area> filterednames = new ArrayList<Area>();
private String filterValue;
private List<Area> listArea;

 public void filterList() {
        List<Area> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(getNames(),
                Predicates.containsPattern(filterValue)));
        setFilterednames(filteredList);
        
//        JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();
//        listArea = new LazyDataModelApiJPA<AreaView>(backendService,
//                apiActiveArea, jSONObject, AreaView[].class) {
//        };
    }
```

I kept getting an error of

> incompatible type inference variable e#1 has incompatible bounds equality constraints: Area

Comment: Are you on Java 8+?

Comment: @Maxes 1) I'm not sure, but don't `()` in `p:command action` cause an EL syntax error? 2) you can't combine `getNames()` (that most likely return a collection of `Area`) with the string predicate returned from `Predicates.containsPattern(...)` without an additional transformation (say, combining the predicate with a transformer using `Predicates.compose`). 3) If for whatever reason you're on pre-8 Java, it's better to use `FluentIterable` that does not produce intermediate collections. 4) `names` are strings, but `filterednames` are `Area`s -- why?

Comment: Xaerxess yes i'm on Java 8+ , fluffy yeah i "kinda know" the incompatible causes but i don't really know about how to filter if it's a List with <Area> datatypes maybe you have something in commong or any references?

Comment: @Maxes well, take a look at the `Predicates.compose` method I mentioned above, then switch either to `FluentIterable` from Google Guava or `Stream` from Java Streams API -- semantically they do the same, but the latter is more preferable since 2014.